# AssertJ: Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.fail

Tags: kotlin, type-inference, junit5, assertj

In a pure Kotlin project I am using JUnit Jupiter 5.5.2 and [AssertJ 3.10.0](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-news.html#assertj-core-3.10.0). The following test executes successful:

```
@Test
fun `Validates something`() = runBlocking {
    try {
        // Assert something
    } catch (t: Throwable) {
        fail("Should not throw $t")
    }
}
```

Once I update to [AssertJ 3.11.1](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-news.html#assertj-core-3.11.1) the test build fails with this message:

> Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in fun  fail(p0: String!): T!
>   Please specify it explicitly.

If I use `fail<Nothing>("Should not throw $t")` then `No test were found`.

I tried to figure out what's going on - without success though.

## Related

- [JUnit5 issue #1209: Can't call "fail" in Kotlin without specifying generic type explicitly](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1209)

Comment: Wouldn't using `fail<Any>` or even `fail<Any?>` help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the problem is with the `runBlocking` expression body. If you turn it into a block body, then it would work no matter which type you use to specify on the `fail` method (using `Nothing` as an example, which can be `Any`, `Any?` or any other types):

```
@Test
fun `Validates something`() {
    runBlocking {
        try {
            // Assert something
        } catch (t: Throwable) {
            fail<Nothing>("Should not throw $t")
        }
    }
}
```